# API Get metod returns null with some letters

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, webapi, getmethod

I'm developing an example API for myself. I'll tell the problem with images.

```
[HttpGet("getbyname")]
public IActionResult GetByName(string name)
{
   var result = _platformService.GetByName(name);

   if (result.Success)
   {
     return Ok(result);
   }

   return BadRequest(result);
}
```

}

this is my get method. I'm trying this url like somedomain.com/getbyname?name=tiktok
its getting a data. But when I try to get to "instagram" its getting null.

[image]

[image]

Because Instagram starts with capital letter. So, when I try to get with "Instagram" its returns true json values.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What does the platformService look like?

Comment: Just a suspicion, but look out for "turquish 'i'" ... maybe you can rule that out. Because: if it's not case sensitive for one value, it shouldn't be for another. But the turquish i has its quirks. One being the conversions "ToUpper" / "ToLower".

Comment: @Fildor yeah, you're right. I change this on Sql with Latin1_General_CI_AS. It was Turkish_CI_AS collation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default configuration of a SQL Server database, string comparisons are case-insensitive.
But your database has this setting changed.
You are looking for this setting:

[image]

See the possible setting here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15